# Group hash of arrays by array element

Tags: ruby

I have this data structure resulted from a query grouping

```
{
  [0, "AR"]=>2,
  [0, nil]=>1,
  [0, "AQ"]=>6,
  [1, nil]=>4,
  [1, "AQ"]=>3,
  [2, "BG"]=>1,
  [2, nil]=>1,
}
```

I want to manipulate it so I end up with a structure grouped like this

```
{
  0 => {
    'AR' => 2,
    'AQ' => 6,
    nil => 1
  },
  1 => {
    'AQ' => 1,
    nil => 4
  },
  2 => {
    'BG' => 1,
    nil => 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```rb
input = {
  [0, "AR"]=>2,
  [0, nil]=>1,
  [0, "AQ"]=>6,
  [1, nil]=>4,
  [1, "AQ"]=>3,
  [2, "BG"]=>1,
  [2, nil]=>1,
}

result = {}

input.each do |k, v|
  if result[k[0]]
    result[k[0]].merge!({ k[1] => v })
  else
    result[k[0]] = { k[1] => v }
  end
end

puts result 
#{0=>{"AR"=>2, nil=>1, "AQ"=>6}, 1=>{nil=>4, "AQ"=>3}, 2=>{"BG"=>1, nil=>1}}
```

I think this is not the most succinct way, I hope some advice!

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {
  [0, "AR"]=>2,
  [0, nil]=>1,
  [0, "AQ"]=>6,
  [1, nil]=>4,
  [1, "AQ"]=>3,
  [2, "BG"]=>1,
  [2, nil]=>1,
}

new_hash = {}

hash.each{|k, v| new_hash[k[0]] ||= {}; new_hash[k[0]].merge!({k[1] => v})}

puts  new_hash # {0=>{"AR"=>2, nil=>1, "AQ"=>6}, 1=>{nil=>4, "AQ"=>3}, 2=>{"BG"=>1, nil=>1}}
```

Comment: conciser  than mine!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more very similar to previous answers but with using of [`#each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```rb
hash = {
  [0, "AR"]=>2,
  [0, nil]=>1,
  [0, "AQ"]=>6,
  [1, nil]=>4,
  [1, "AQ"]=>3,
  [2, "BG"]=>1,
  [2, nil]=>1,
}

result_hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
hash.each_with_object(result_hash) do |((parrent_key, key), value), res|
  res[parrent_key].merge!(key => value)
end

=> {0=>{"AR"=>2, nil=>1, "AQ"=>6}, 1=>{nil=>4, "AQ"=>3}, 2=>{"BG"=>1, nil=>1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an answer that doesn't require additional variable assignments in its enclosing scope (it has "referential transparency": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

```
input
.group_by { |(arr, num)| arr.first }
.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |(key, vals), hsh|
  vals.each do |((key, innerkey), innerval)|
    hsh[key] ||= {}
    hsh[key][innerkey] = innerval
  end
  hsh
end
# {0=>{"AR"=>2, nil=>1, "AQ"=>6}, 1=>{nil=>4, "AQ"=>3}, 2=>{"BG"=>1, nil=>1}}
```

Two high-level steps:

1. I noticed the output object is grouped by the first array element (here, 0/1/2).  I use `#group_by` to create a hash with that structure.

```
# output of `#group_by` on first array element:
key: 0, vals: [ [[0, "AR"], 2],  [[0, nil],  1],  [[0, "AQ"], 6] ]
key: 1, vals: [ [[1, nil],  4],  [[1, "AQ"], 3]                  ]
key: 2, vals: [ [[2, "BG"], 1],  [[2, nil],  1]                  ]
```

2. I use `#each_with_object` to construct the nested hashes.  For each `vals` array above, I extracted the second and third values by destructuring the arrays in the block parameter (`((key, innerkey), innerval)`) and then the hash assignment was straightforward.

Comment: elegant solution